# how to set --network=host in docker_image via ansible

Tags: ansible, docker-compose, ansible-2.x

I want to replace this command with an ansible playbook

```
'docker build -q --network host -t "ubuntu" . '
```

I have been going through [docker_image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/docker_image_module.html) module of ansible but couldn't figure it out. Any idea on how to proceed further?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `network_mode: host` to your docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Go to the [`docker_image` module source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_image.py), add the feature, make (or not) a pull request to the repo.

Comment: @mulg0r there is no docker-compose.yml file it there is just a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest you can have it is:

```
---
- name: build the image
  docker_image:
    name: docker
    tag: ubuntu
    path: "/yourpath"
    state: present
```

For the --network host, there is a request open in [Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21433) to have it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `network_mode: host` to your `docker_container` task. Here is a working example:

```
---
- name: deploy whoami
  hosts: docker01
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: install whoami server
      docker_container:
        name: whoami
        image: traefik/whoami
        state: started
        recreate: true
        network_mode: host
```